# Cannot upgrade to 22.04 from 21.10 as some packages are kept back

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, 22.04, held-packages

I am trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 21.10 to Ubuntu 22.04. The notification to upgrade to 22.04 also came automatically. However upgradation did not work.

On trying to upgrade to LTS version using terminal, the following message is printed

```
$sudo do-release-upgrade 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

The `sudo apt upgrade` print the following message:

```
 The following packages have been kept back:
      cups cups-bsd cups-client cups-core-drivers cups-daemon cups-ipp-utils dirmngr ffmpeg gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data gnupg gnupg-l10n gnupg-utils gpg gpg-agent gpg-wks-client gpg-wks-server gpgconf gpgsm gpgv ldap-utils libavcodec58 libavdevice58 libavfilter7 libavformat58 libavutil56 libcups2 libcupsimage2 libcurl3-gnutls libfreerdp2-2 libinput-bin libinput10 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 libldap-2.5-0 libpostproc55 libswresample3 libswscale5 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libwinpr2-2 libxml2 ntfs-3g xserver-xephyr xserver-xorg-core xvfb xwayland
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 47 not upgraded.
```

On trying to manually update or install any one of the above packages, it simply prints long list of dependency errors.

I do not how to resolve this. This problem has been asked quite a lot here at `AskUbuntu` but the solutions suggested did not work for me.

Is there any way to supress the error in these packages and move forward with upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04?

**Update**

The output of `sudo apt update` is as follows:

```
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                         
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                     
Hit:3 https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
47 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

The output of `sudo apt upgrade` is as follows:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  cups cups-bsd cups-client cups-core-drivers cups-daemon cups-ipp-utils dirmngr ffmpeg gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0
  gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data gnupg gnupg-l10n gnupg-utils gpg gpg-agent
  gpg-wks-client gpg-wks-server gpgconf gpgsm gpgv ldap-utils libavcodec58 libavdevice58 libavfilter7 libavformat58
  libavutil56 libcups2 libcupsimage2 libcurl3-gnutls libfreerdp2-2 libinput-bin libinput10 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18
  libldap-2.5-0 libpostproc55 libswresample3 libswscale5 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libwinpr2-2 libxml2 ntfs-3g xserver-xephyr
  xserver-xorg-core xvfb xwayland
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 47 not upgraded.
```

The list of external PPA's are as follows:

```
ppa:costales/yaru-colors-folder-color
ppa:linuxuprising/apps
ppa:numix/ppa
ppa:team-xbmc/ppa
ppa:kelebek333/mint-tools
```

The output of `sudo apt full-upgrade` is as follows:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  cups cups-bsd cups-client cups-core-drivers cups-daemon cups-ipp-utils dirmngr
  gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data
  gnupg gnupg-l10n gnupg-utils gpg gpg-agent gpg-wks-client gpg-wks-server gpgconf gpgsm gpgv
  ldap-utils libavcodec58 libavformat58 libavutil56 libcups2 libcupsimage2 libcurl3-gnutls
  libfreerdp2-2 libinput-bin libinput10 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 libldap-2.5-0 libpostproc55
  libswresample3 libswscale5 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libwinpr2-2 libxml2 ntfs-3g xserver-xephyr
  xserver-xorg-core xvfb xwayland
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 44 not upgraded.
```

**Update (18 July 2022)**

The output of `apt-cache policy cups` is as follows:

```
cups:
  Installed: 2.3.3op2-7ubuntu2
  Candidate: 2.4.1op1-1ubuntu4.1
  Version table:
     2.4.1op1-1ubuntu4.1 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.3.3op2-7ubuntu2 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

The output of `apt-cache policy cups cups-daemon libcups2` is given below:

```
cups:
  Installed: 2.3.3op2-7ubuntu2
  Candidate: 2.4.1op1-1ubuntu4.1
  Version table:
     2.4.1op1-1ubuntu4.1 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.3.3op2-7ubuntu2 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
cups-daemon:
  Installed: 2.3.3op2-7ubuntu2
  Candidate: 2.4.1op1-1ubuntu4.1
  Version table:
     2.4.1op1-1ubuntu4.1 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.3.3op2-7ubuntu2 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libcups2:
  Installed: 2.3.3op2-7ubuntu2
  Candidate: 2.4.1op1-1ubuntu4.1
  Version table:
     2.4.1op1-1ubuntu4.1 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.3.3op2-7ubuntu2 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

The output of `sudo apt upgrade cups` is given below:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cups : Depends: cups-client (>= 2.4.1op1-1ubuntu4.1)
        Depends: cups-daemon (>= 2.4.1op1-1ubuntu4.1)
        Depends: libcups2 (= 2.4.1op1-1ubuntu4.1) but 2.3.3op2-7ubuntu2 is to be installed
 cups-core-drivers : Depends: cups-daemon (>= 2.4.1op1-1ubuntu4.1)
                     Depends: libcups2 (= 2.4.1op1-1ubuntu4.1) but 2.3.3op2-7ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

The output of `apt-cache policy` is given below:

```
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial/main amd64 Packages
     release o=. xenial,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=. xenial,c=main,b=amd64
     origin updates.signal.org
 500 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
     release v=1.0,o=Google LLC,a=stable,n=stable,l=Google,c=main,b=amd64
     origin dl.google.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
Pinned packages:
```

Comment: Your system must be up-to-date before you can release upgrade. We need more information in order to help you get your system up-to-date. Please edit your question and include the full output of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: ... and provide information on any external PPA's you may have added.

Comment: Don't forget there are cases where an `apt upgrade` will not install all upgrades; thus the existence of `apt dist-upgrade` or `apt full-upgrade`. You (or user of system) may also have put holds on packages preventing that from working (`apt-mark showhold`), but you must upgrade all first & cannot suppress them for the [Ubuntu Release Upgrade tool](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader) to function just as the message says.  Try `apt full-upgrade` if you had a clean `apt update`

Comment: @guiverc Added the output of ``sudo apt full-upgrade``. The result is same.

Comment: @guiverc Yes. ``apt-mark showhold`` prints no output.

Comment: `apt-cache policy cups` and `sudo apt upgrade cups` please add this to your question.

Comment: @nobody added to question.

Comment: looks like mixing packages from impish and jammy to me.  Please `apt-cache policy`

Comment: @nobody added the output ``apt-cache policy``.

Answer (score 1):

please make a backup from your personal data and make sure you have a installmedia for jammy just in case.

In /etc/apt/sources.list add jammy updates source.

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and add line

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted multiverse universe
```

then refresh

```
sudo apt update && apt -s -f install
```

the second part is only a similation. If apt nor dpkg are not complaining about errors.

```
sudo apt -f install && sudo apt full-upgrade
```

Comment: This works for me. downvote for ubuntu for this issue. I used ubuntu for years this is the first time I got this issue. it is so unfriendly. I have to consider other Linux alternatives then.